# What kind of arthropod/animal is this?

Tags: zoology, species-identification

[image]

Can anyone identify this strange creature? I live in a very urban part of Montreal, Canada. It wasn't moving (seemed dead) and although the image is huge, it wasn't as big as it seems (a couple of centimeters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a type of centipede.

Based on the long legs, I would bet on something like that:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutigera_coleoptrata

Or at least a Scutigeromorpha http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutigeromorpha#Scutigeromorpha

Answer (score 2):

I live in Japan and here they are called "gejigeji". As mentioned, they are a member of the centipede family and are as creepy as hell. I live in a newly-built house, so thankfully there are no cockroaches, but every now and again one of these little blighters will scurry across my floor in my peripheral vision and scare the bejesus out of me.

They are not dangerous (at least not to humans). I have been told they eat the larvae of other insects, like cockroaches so they are not so bad really. Also, and I assume this is just a Japanese myth, but it's said they hunt in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common house centipede. Apparently they're everywhere but I've never seen one before.